# Getting Paths that cover all the nodes and Start and End at Special Nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have this graph problem where i have a number of  Nodes (bus stops ) and some  Special nodes (Bus Stations) , I have to cover all the Nodes - Assign bus routes that cover all of them - while starting and ending at a station and I have some restrictions on number of busses I can use , Any ideas how I should start?

Comment: When you say cover, do you mean visit? And are you allowed to visit nodes more than once? If not, it's almost like finding a Hamiltonian Path (visit each node once).

Comment: As stated, it seems you could solve your problem for any number of nodes with a single route.  Do you have something that you are trying to optimize or some other restrictions on the route?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding the shortest path that connects all nodes (with the bus stations restriction) is reduceable from the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with the reduction of: given a TSP problem, create an instance of this problem with 1/2 stations/"special nodes" (depending weither or not you can come back to the same station).

Using this reduction - if this problem is solveable polynomially - so is TSP.

Thus - the problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and **there is no known polynomial solution** to it ([and the assumption is - one does not exist, though it is not proven yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem))

Some alternative are heuristic algorithms such as [Genetic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) and [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), approximation algorithms, or exponential algorithms  (which can be used to find an optimal solutions if the data is relatively small) like Dynamic Programming or [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

**EDIT:** (response to edited question)

Even if you can use several buses - but a *limited number* of them - the problem is still NP-Hard, because (assuming the number of buses is constant/given in unary coding): you can "duplicate" the graph to `k` distinct components (where `k` is the limited number of buses) - and you have yourself a new TSP problem for each component.

Comment: in my problem i can come back to the same station ,but can you please elaborate more ??

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoudFathy: The relaxation of "coming back to a station more then once" for TSP does not make the problem "easier" - it is still NP-Hard, thus the reduction still stands, and the problem is still NP-Hard. What do you want me to elaborate on specifically? :|

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea:

1. Remove the start and end node from the graph.
2. Search for the minimum spanning tree
3. Connect the start-end node to the spanning tree.

With that you can have a minimal cover solution.

Of course, if you need to visit each node once, then as stated, this is an NP-Hard problem.